# What's the point (or usage) of AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM?

Tags: java, android

I noticed that the Android documentation states that [AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#ACCESS_RANDOM) field may be used by [AssetManager.open(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to "Read chunks, and seek forward and **backward**".

But the InputStream interface (or AssetInputStream) only provides methods for sequential forward access and the documentation states that [AssetInputStream.markSupported()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.AssetInputStream.html#markSupported%28%29) always returns false.

So what's the use case for `AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM`?

Comment: did you try to use `seek` with a negative value ?

Comment: AssetInputStream doesn't have a `seek` method. If you mean `skip`, the documentation states: "This method does nothing and returns 0 if n is negative [...]"